# is it possible to use xsd on WCF consumer side?

Tags: wcf, xsd, websphere, ibm-mq

I want to connect to an IBM WebSphere queue as a consumer. I have the xsd of the types that I will get on this queue.

Is it possible to use WCF and this way make the connection between the receiving object and generate this receiving object to class?

What I mean is that I want to connect to the queue and by using WCF and the xsd that I hold I will receive the real object that the producer is adding the the queue for me.

Is it possible ?

How to do it ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to consume a service, and you have only the xsd schema?